# PHP images returning 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, image, http-headers

I have some code that adds some headers to an image:

Contents of title-background.png.php:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("title-background.png");

header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Expires: 19 Febuary 2012 20:00:00 GMT');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

And that's working fine. But when I tried to do the same with another file,

Contents of button.png.php:

```
<?php
$im1 = imagecreatefrompng("button.png");

header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Expires: 19 Febuary 2012 20:00:00 GMT');

imagepng($im1);
imagedestroy($im1);
?>
```

The server returns with 500.
I have no access to my logs.

Comment: Did you check the path to the image? Do you have access to the file?

Comment: Try adding these lines to the beginning of the file to prevent 500 error, then see if you get a php error: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); echo "aaa"; ob_flush(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, Sorry guys - cluttering up the stackoverflow server. Withing 1mins over my breakfast I worked it out...

the title-background.png.php was pointed to from a .css fie ON THE SAME SERVER :- however, the button.png.php was from a DIFFERENT SERVER!

I have now fixed it by putting the full paths, including http://'s and the such.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `button.png` doesn't exist, can't be read, or is somehow incompatible with `imagecreatefrompng()`.

Comment: Do you think that incorrect format or not exist file can cause 500?

Comment: @zerkms: If the SAPI used by the server to handle PHP or if a custom framework used is configured to return a 500 status code on `E_ERROR`, yes.